# ZendX_JQuery plugin is there a way to load jQuery plugin with echo $this->jquery()

Tags: jquery, zend-framework, zendx

I am having a problem with ZendX_JQquery. problem is that jquery loads with

```
echo $this->jQuery()
```

and jquery plugin loads with

```
$echo $this->headScript();
```

now if i echo out headscript before jquery, i get an error message because plygin depends on jquery. and i have on load function load function loaded with

```
$jquery->addOnload('some function');
```

it echos out with jquery before the plugin and get an error message. is there a way to load jquery plugin with jquery method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add JavaScript files to the JQuery Stack.

```
<?php
//index.phtml

$plugin = '/public/js/plugins/xyz.js';

// add plugin to Jquery "echO"
echo $this->jQuery()->addJavascriptFile($plugin);
```